# how to fix Could not automatically detect an ADB binary on macbook

Tags: android, android-studio

how to fix? on macbook

"Could not automatically detect an ADB binary. Some emulator functionality will not work until a custom path to ADB is added. This can be done in Extended Controls (...) > Settings > General tab > 'Use Detected ADB location'".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McjoI.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a new macbook pro ARM ?
You need to use ARM emulator image.